# jQuery lava-lamp-like effect bouncing all over the place!

Tags: jquery, hover, lavalamp

I followed the tutorial found here and added my own flare to it:  [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-lava-lamp-style-navigation-menu/)

What I was looking to accomplish was to put a specific image on the left and right side of the list item.  So instead of just the generic `<li id="blob"></li>` created in the tutorial, I did `<li id="blob"><div class="blob-wrap"><div class="leftimage"></div><div class="rightimage"></div></li>` to accomplish the particular effect I wanted.  It works beautifully ... except that the image attempts to bounce back the "currentPageItem" if I leave the mouse hovering over one of the list items.

Here's a JS Bin example: http://jsbin.com/odome

What do I need to do to fix it?  jQuery is firing the "hoverOut" function (or whatever you want to call it).  But why?

Comment: OK, I think it's actually the z-index, now that I play with the CSS instead of the javascript.  But even setting the z-index to 900 and the #blob's z-index to 1, it still resets the animation sequence.  Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index was, indeed, the problem.  I didn't realize that z-indexes didn't apply to floated elements though.  I had to apply `position: relative` to the `a` links and give it a z-index higher than the blob.